# Split View into four Subviews with 25% width

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

[image]

I want to insert 4 Subviews with **exact 25% percent width of the SuperView.**

So, my question is how to achieve that with XCode's Autolayout? In Android I would use a GridLayout or a LinearLayout...

Thanks in advance

Comment: use equal width constraints

Comment: yes, but at least one of them has to be 25% of the superview, right?

Comment: yes....it automatically adjust 4 views width if you give it equal width

Comment: No, just set for all subviews "equal width" constrains. 25% should be calculated automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set your constraints like this image,you will get what you want

[image]

And this is preview in different screen sizes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to select all the four views, and add top, bottom, left, right constraints to zero and equal width constraint.

Your constraints should look like this.

[image]

In the screenshot, the four views are arranged over a container view. If you dont't want the container view, then you have to specify the height constraint also.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIStackView that is introduce in ios9 and xcode 7.0

Here is a link of the tutorial have a look its like a linear layout in android

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-uistackview--cms-24193

There are alot other ways as this is the new one and it help to reduce work and time both so you should use it.Thanks

Comment: Using autolayout u should select 4 views and assign them equal width , Than assign width to any view by making its referenceoutlet and assinging thatoutlet like view1WidthOutlet.constant = self.superView.frame.size.width/4; , it will automatically convert allviews to same width, or u should use uicollectionView